# zxing not found exception in android

Tags: android, zxing

Hello everyone,

If any one of you can help me this. I am using zxing to decode barCode image, but it returns com.google.zxing.NotFoundException, don't know why. The same image gets decoded via Intent provided to zxing, but not when I use it to decode from image file.

The code that I am using is below :

```
mMultiFormatReader = new MultiFormatReader();
mMultiFormatReader.setHints(null);

BinaryBitmap bitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(new RGBLuminanceSource(path)));
Result result = mMultiFormatReader.decodeWithState(bitmap);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's exactly the same image, since you can't have it scan a file by Intent. I assume you mean that you can scan the image off your screen fine, but the image itself does not decode.

That's just life, really. Some images won't happen to decode. But you may try TRY_HARDER mode or use a different binarizer to see if that works.

Comment: Yes i have tried with TRY_HARDER, this is usually occurring with small images. I am testing this further and if only the size is the reason, i will put certain restrictions.........

Comment: Size is not the reason. It's just that occasionally an image will not decode. This is working as intended.

Comment: Well most of the gif's are not getting decoded via my code snippet. Although i haven't found a complete soln, still I am accepting ur answer. Thanks for help............

Comment: Very small images (maybe 200x200 or less) may not have enough resolution to decode well.