# Android zxing NotFoundException

Tags: android, zxing

I'm using zxing to decode QRcode images, but it always returns a NotFoundException. The online decoder at http://zxing.org/w/decode.jspx scans these images perfectly fine, so it should be able to do so in my app.
I'm using this code :

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/QRPictures/QRTest.bmp";
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
int[] pixels = new int[bmp.getWidth()*bmp.getHeight()];
bmp.getPixels(pixels, 0, bmp.getWidth(), 0, 0, bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight());
LuminanceSource source = new RGBLuminanceSource(bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), pixels); 
BinaryBitmap bitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source));
Reader reader = new MultiFormatReader();
try {
    Result result = reader.decode(bitmap);
    String contents = result.getText(); 
    Log.d(TAG, content);
} catch (NotFoundException e) {
    Log.d(TAG, "NFE");
} catch (ChecksumException e) {
    Log.d(TAG, "CSE");
} catch (FormatException e) {
    Log.d(TAG, "FE");
}
```

Could you help with this please ?

Answer (score 1):

According to [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7416253/520779) to a related question, using the [`TRY_HARDER`](http://zxing.org/w/docs/javadoc/com/google/zxing/DecodeHintType.html#TRY_HARDER) decode hint might help, since it "optmizes for accuracy, not speed":

```
Hashtable<DecodeHintType, Object> decodeHints = new Hashtable<DecodeHintType, Object>();
decodeHints.put(DecodeHintType.TRY_HARDER, Boolean.TRUE);
Result result = reader.decode(bitmap, decodeHints);
```

If the **same image** is being correctly interpreted in the online service but failing in your case, it's probable that they have `TRY_HARDER` on while you have it off.

Comment: I still got the NotFoundException, even with TRY_HARDER

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too. And I solved it.
Try add this hint to your code:

```
hints.put(DecodeHintType.PURE_BARCODE, Boolean.TRUE);
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by: `hints.put(DecodeHintType.PURE_BARCODE, Boolean.TRUE);`