# zxing does not find readable barcode

Tags: zxing

I try to detect barcodes in webcam images and have problems to find small barcodes in a large image. xzing (svn trunk) fails to find the barcode in the first image (See links) even with try-harder. If I however manually crop the image (second image) it has no problem extracting the information. So it should also be possible to find the barcode in the first image.

Is there a way to tell xzing to also find smaller barcodes? Or is there already some sliding window implemented or maybe a gradient based barcode localizer?

Original: No barcode found
http://postimg.org/image/lh9xf7lw1/

Cropped Version: Barcode extracted
http://postimg.org/image/e1kb49tw1/

Comment: It won't help for Barcodes, but for QRCodes, I've found that switching to [QRCodeMultiReader](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/blob/master/core/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/multi/qrcode/QRCodeMultiReader.java) dramatically improves the ability to find small QR codes within larger images

Answer (score 1):

Try different binarizers. You are probably using the one that computes a histogram over the whole image. The varied brightness causes the barcode itself to be treated as more uniform patch of black. The hybrid binarizer is more localized and likely to get the same effect as cutting out the rest of the image manually.

Comment: I already tried both binarizers and also zxing.org fails to read the barcode. [~/projects...-read-only/cpp/build]: ./zxing -h  large_fail.png 
Hybrid binarizer failed: zxing::ReaderException: No code detected

Comment: It could be a lag between the C++ and Java port. But it may also just be an image that doesn't decode. It's not guaranteed to find the barcode.

Comment: Do you plan to integrate a Barcode Localizer into zxing? I've implemented an OpenCV-based localizer which improves the detection rate of zxing by selecting a good roi. Are there test cases in which the barcode is hard to find within the image?

Comment: I don't have any plans at all for zxing, but I think it's got some proper bindings for Android now, so I bet it would be straightforward

Answer (score 1):

In my case this tip helped
[Android zxing NotFoundException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994674/android-zxing-notfoundexception)

It suggests adding TRY_HARDER

```
        Hashtable<DecodeHintType, Object> decodeHints = new Hashtable<>();
        decodeHints.put(DecodeHintType.TRY_HARDER, Boolean.TRUE);

        result = reader.decode(bitmap, decodeHints);
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?