# NotFoundException even when a barcode is in the picture

Tags: java, swing, webcam, zxing

I am trying to make a simple barcode scanner project for fun. And I've run into a slight problem. I am using zXing and Webcam Capture for this.

Even if a Barcode is present in the picture, Java keeps telling me none is found through the `NotFoundException`. I look for a frame every time webcamImageObtained is run (which I assume is every frame?) and then I look for a barcode in the frame that I captured.

I took this picture with that webcam (Ironically using the code hah):

[image: barcode]

When I hover over this barcode it reports about 30 images per second and otherwise about 7-8 when it looks at me from my screen (if that means anything).

Whenever I find a code, I want to add it to a `JList` (not accounting for duplicates and the likes yet).

I call this code every time `webcamImageObtained(WebcamEvent we)` fires:

```
@Override
    public void webcamImageObtained(WebcamEvent we) {
        BufferedImage myImage;
        try {
            myImage = webcam.getImage();
            LuminanceSource source = new BufferedImageLuminanceSource(myImage);
            BinaryBitmap bitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source));
            Result result = reader.decode(bitmap);
            DefaultListModel dlm = (DefaultListModel) list.getModel();
            dlm.addElement(result.toString());
            list.setModel(dlm);
        } catch (NotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(AdvancedWebcamPanelExample.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (ChecksumException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(AdvancedWebcamPanelExample.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (FormatException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(AdvancedWebcamPanelExample.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

Here is the entire class:

```
package sandbox_webcam;

import com.github.sarxos.webcam.Webcam;
import com.github.sarxos.webcam.WebcamDiscoveryEvent;
import com.github.sarxos.webcam.WebcamDiscoveryListener;
import com.github.sarxos.webcam.WebcamEvent;
import com.github.sarxos.webcam.WebcamListener;
import com.github.sarxos.webcam.WebcamPanel;
import com.github.sarxos.webcam.WebcamPicker;
import com.github.sarxos.webcam.WebcamResolution;
import com.google.zxing.BinaryBitmap;
import com.google.zxing.ChecksumException;
import com.google.zxing.FormatException;
import com.google.zxing.LuminanceSource;
import com.google.zxing.NotFoundException;
import com.google.zxing.Result;
import com.google.zxing.client.j2se.BufferedImageLuminanceSource;
import com.google.zxing.common.HybridBinarizer;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class AdvancedWebcamPanelExample extends JFrame implements Runnable, WebcamListener, WindowListener, UncaughtExceptionHandler, ItemListener, WebcamDiscoveryListener {

    private Webcam webcam = null;
    private WebcamPanel panel = null;
    private WebcamPicker picker = null;
    private JButton button = null;
    private JList list = null;
    private ActionListener buttonListener = null;
    private com.google.zxing.Reader reader = new com.google.zxing.MultiFormatReader();

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Webcam.addDiscoveryListener(this);

        setTitle("Java Webcam Capture POC");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        addWindowListener(this);

        picker = new WebcamPicker();
        picker.addItemListener(this);

        webcam = picker.getSelectedWebcam();

        if (webcam == null) {
            System.out.println("No webcams found...");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        webcam.setViewSize(WebcamResolution.VGA.getSize());
        webcam.addWebcamListener(AdvancedWebcamPanelExample.this);

        panel = new WebcamPanel(webcam, false);
        panel.setFPSDisplayed(true);

        buttonListener = new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (webcam != null) {
                    BufferedImage image = webcam.getImage();
                    JFileChooser filechooser = new JFileChooser();

                    int saveValue = filechooser.showDialog(button, "Save");
                    if (saveValue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                        try {
                            File f = filechooser.getSelectedFile();
                            ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File(f.getAbsolutePath() + ".png"));
                            System.out.println("Picture saved at: " + f.getAbsolutePath());
                        } catch (IOException ex) {
                            System.err.println("Failed to save the picture!");
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    System.err.println("no webcam found to take a picture");
                }
            }
        };

        button = new JButton("Snap a Picture!");
        button.addActionListener(buttonListener);
        list = new JList();
        list.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(200,this.getHeight()));

        add(picker, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        add(list, BorderLayout.EAST);

        pack();
        setVisible(true);

        Thread t = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                panel.start();
            }
        };

        t.setName("example-starter");
        t.setDaemon(true);
        t.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(this);
        t.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void webcamOpen(WebcamEvent we) {
        System.out.println("webcam open");
    }

    @Override
    public void webcamClosed(WebcamEvent we) {
        System.out.println("webcam closed");
    }

    @Override
    public void webcamDisposed(WebcamEvent we) {
        System.out.println("webcam disposed");
    }

    @Override
    public void webcamImageObtained(WebcamEvent we) {
        BufferedImage myImage;
        try {
            myImage = webcam.getImage();
            LuminanceSource source = new BufferedImageLuminanceSource(myImage);
            BinaryBitmap bitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source));
            Result result = reader.decode(bitmap);
            DefaultListModel dlm = (DefaultListModel) list.getModel();
            dlm.addElement(result.toString());
            list.setModel(dlm);
        } catch (NotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(AdvancedWebcamPanelExample.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (ChecksumException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(AdvancedWebcamPanelExample.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (FormatException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(AdvancedWebcamPanelExample.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {
        // do nothing
    }

    @Override
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        // do nothing
    }

    @Override
    public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
        webcam.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e) {
        System.out.println("webcam viewer paused");
        panel.pause();
    }

    @Override
    public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e) {
        System.out.println("webcam viewer resumed");
        panel.resume();
    }

    @Override
    public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e) {
        // do nothing
    }

    @Override
    public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e) {
        // do nothing
    }

    @Override
    public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
        System.err.println(String.format("Exception in thread #s", t.getName()));
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    @Override
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
        if (e.getItem() != webcam) {
            if (webcam != null) {
                panel.stop();

                remove(panel);
                webcam.removeWebcamListener(this);
                webcam.close();

                webcam = (Webcam) e.getItem();
                webcam.setViewSize(WebcamResolution.VGA.getSize());
                webcam.addWebcamListener(this);

                System.out.println("selected " + webcam.getName());

                panel = new WebcamPanel(webcam, false);
                panel.setFPSDisplayed(true);

                add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                pack();

                Thread t = new Thread() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        panel.start();
                    }
                };

                t.setName("example-stopper");
                t.setDaemon(true);
                t.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(this);
                t.start();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void webcamFound(WebcamDiscoveryEvent event) {
        if (picker != null) {
            picker.addItem(event.getWebcam());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void webcamGone(WebcamDiscoveryEvent event) {
        if (picker != null) {
            picker.removeItem(event.getWebcam());
        }
    }

}
```

Am I missing something about how this library scans for a barcode?

**EDIT**

Not sure this helps much..

```
Mar 02, 2015 10:04:34 PM sandbox_webcam.AdvancedWebcamPanelExample webcamImageObtained
SEVERE: null
com.google.zxing.NotFoundException
```

Throws exception here:

```
Result result = reader.decode(bitmap);
```

Comment: We need stacktrace of that error and highlite the lines, where it happens.

Comment: @libik Sure..not sure it helps that much in this case.

Comment: It is still not the entire stacktrace :).

Comment: @libik Yep, that is literally the only thing it spits out.

Comment: What spits out, if you rewrite it to `ex.printStackTrace()`?

Comment: @libik calling `printStackTrace()` prints out `com.google.zxing.NotFoundException` . I am not kidding.

Comment: No one got anything..? :c

Comment: This question has some things you can try in the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994674/android-zxing-notfoundexception

Comment: How does the image look after converting it to black-and-white? Is the barcode really still visible?

Comment: I'm curious as to if you taking the pictures of an image on a monitor might impact your output. Have you tried scanning physical barcodes not on screen? Do you get the same output?

Comment: @James I tried on physical barcodes first and then tried to get a crystal clear one from a screen. Same result either way, but I am going to try what Philipp Wendler suggested later today :)

Comment: @PhilippWendler I followed the question and used the solution. It now works! Thanks! The trick is though, if the FPS on my camera is too low (aka the exposure to light is too low) it cannot find the barcodes at all. The FPS needs to be stable and probably above 15 or 20 (which it will be with better light). The FPS is about 30 when I point it at my screen, and it can read the barcode just fine there. If you want, you can make your comment an answer, I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a different question which has some available answers: [Android zxing NotFoundException](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14994674/396730)

As James said, it is a good idea to try with bar codes on different media (paper/screen) if it is not working, and in different circumstances and lighting conditions. Particularly ensure that you have enough light, and that the FPS of the camera is high enough while it is pointed at the barcode.

For debugging, one could also convert the `BinaryImage` back into a viewable format and check whether the barcode is actually visible after conversion to black-and-white.